# C gives me an error when trying to make a simple function. How can I fix it?

Tags: c

I am trying to learn C but when trying to make a function I get an error.

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    sayHi("Isaac", 14);
    return 0;
}

void sayHi(char name[], int age){
    printf("Hello %s! You are %d\n", name, age);
}
```

When I try to run this I get an error that says this:

Warning: Implicit declaration of function 'sayHi' is invalid in C99
Warning: This function declaration is not a prototype

Error: Conflicting types for 'sayHi'

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Put the function before `main`, or put a function prototype before `main`.

Comment: And suggest you learn to make effective use of search. If you just type in the exact error you will get many useful results.

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler examines `main`, it notices that you've referenced a function that it doesn't know about.  It doesn't need to know the code for `sayHi` at this point but it does need to know what kind of arguments that function takes as well as what kind of value it returns.

This can be accomplished by a function declaration at the top of your code.

```
void sayHi(char name[], int age);
```

Once again, this is all C needs at this moment.  This line tells the compiler that there is some function called `sayHi` with the specified arguments and return value.  The actual code for the function, also known as the function's definition, can occur later as you have it.

Comment: For completeness: Specifying the types like this `void sayHi(char[], int);` would do.